# Measuring Android MediaRecorder delay

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

Android's MediaRecorder class introduces a significant (order of magnitude a second) delay when recording video. See e.g. [Delay in preparing media recorder on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439691/delay-in-preparing-media-recorder-on-android).

After extensive searching, I can't find a way to get rid of this, only workarounds avoiding MediaRecorder and using onPreviewFrame instead.

In my particular application, MediaRecorder's delay wouldn't be so bad if I could measure it programatically -- assuming its standard deviation wasn't too high under everyday background load conditions. Does anyone know how to do that?

I thought of using a FileObserver on the recorded file to find out when frames start being written but, since I don't know the pipeline delays, I couldn't draw a firm conclusion from that.

On a related note, does anyone know if the 'recording alert' sound is played before the first frame is recorded? Is there a way of turning that sound off?